# Using Belkin 6-Outlet Surge Protector in Morocco without a Converter

Tags: surge-protection

Morocco uses the 220V/50Hz standard, and I was trying to use the following power strip I bought in the US with only a adapter (no converter):

https://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-BE106000-06/

When I plugged the surge protector and turned it on (with no load), there was a very short but intense spark. However, my electronics were charging fine when I later plugged them into the surge protector. I'm just wondering what the initial spark was due to, and if it is possible that I broke something inside the surge protector and if so, is it ok to continue to use the surge protector (given that my electronics were still charging fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surge protector itself is what has failed, ones intended for 120V supplies will conduct at typically 200V or so. It's a little component with a resistive element that changes with voltage, so it conducts momentary overvoltages to limit what gets to the equipment. Most likely after plugging it into the 220V supply, if it didn't manage to take out the fuse first it will have either exploded or melted its connections - they're only intended to conduct for milliseconds.[image]

As to whether the strip is still safe to use, it will depend on what debris is now present inside the housing.

Comment: So assuming that the surge protector debris hasn't short circuit the power lines, then the strip is still safe?

Comment: For myself, I wouldn't use it without checking the damage. There's a possibility that there is metallic debris that could be moved across clearance gaps by handling - these strips often use uninsulated formed copper busbars held in locating features in the molding.

Answer (score 0):

Define safe.

It is not a surge protector anymore, it's just an unprotected power strip with blown and unknown components inside.

Can it still work as a power strip? sure. If there are no dangerous debris from the blown component and the rest of the internal components are rated for your line voltage. Then it is just a bunch of wires and connectors.

Now, if any of the remaining internal components (e.g., filter capacitors and fuse) are not rated for your line voltage, something else will be failing in it soon enough.

Comment: If all my electronics are rated 100-240V 50/60Hz, is there a chance for the damaged power strip to indirectly affect electronics

Comment: If a component becomes an intermittent short you can have arcing which will interact with the inductance of your power lines or internal filtering and could introduce high-voltage spikes into your electronics. This is in the realm of possibilities.